# Postgres Paginating a FTS Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, pagination, full-text-search, postgresql-9.1

What is the best way to paginate a FTS Query ? `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` spring to mind. However, I am concerned that by using limit and offset I'd be running the same query over and over (i.e., once for page 1, another time for page 2.... etc).

Will PostgreSQL be smart enough to transparently cache the query result ? Thus subsequently satisfying the pagination queries from a cache ? If not, how do I paginate efficiently ?

**edit**

The database is for single user desktop analytics. But, I still want to know what the best way is, if this were a live OLTP application. I have addressed the problem in the past with SQL Server by creating a ordered set of document id's and cache the query parameters against the IDs in a seperate table. Clearing the cache every few hours (so as to allow new documents to enter the result set).

Perhaps this approach is viable for postgres. But still I wanna know the mechanics present in the database and how best to leverage them. If I were a DB developer I'd enable the query-response cache to work with the FTS system.

Answer (score 3):

**A server-side SQL cursor** can be effectively used for this **if** a client session can be tied to a specific db connection that stays open during the entire session. This is because cursors cannot be shared between different connections. But if it's a desktop app with a unique connection per running instance, that's fine.

The doc for [DECLARE CURSOR](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-declare.html) explains how the resultset is going to be materialized when the cursor is declared `WITH HOLD` in a committed transaction.

**Locking** shouldn't be a concern at all. Should the data be modified while the cursor is already materialized, it wouldn't affect the reader nor block the writer.

Other than that, there is no implicit query cache in PostgreSQL. The LIMIT/OFFSET technique implies a new execution of the query for each page, which may be as slow as the initial query depending on the complexity of the execution plan and the effectiveness of the buffer cache and disk cache.

Comment: Didn't knew you could do this with (PostGre) SQL.

Comment: There's a caveat with server-side cursors in Pg, and that's that while the open transaction exists the server can't free disk space for any rows deleted from tables after the cursor was created. That's OK if they exist for a few minutes, but can be a problem if the user leaves their client running overnight (or while they go on holiday), as it'll hold autovaccum up and cause severe table bloat. I *think* `HOLD` cursors are safe from this so long as you don't hold the transaction open, though.

Comment: I'd still want to add a timer in the app that disposed of cursors after a certain period of inactivity and re-created them when activity resumed, at least in cases where I could easily note the cursor position and resume later.

Comment: The caveat only applies if done wrong, i.e. if keeping the transaction open during user interaction, which a GUI must never do anyway. As for vacuum, the source tables for a HOLD cursor that outlives its transaction can be vacuumed. They could even be dropped if necessary. Technically, the result is materialized in temporary storage until the cursor is closed or the session is terminated.

Comment: Approximately, how much faster would be using the `CURSOR` approach versus the `LIMIT OFFSET` approach (I'm talking about a volume of around 2M records per table)?

Answer (score 2):

Well, to be honest, what you may want is for your query to return a live Cursor, that you can then reuse to fetch certain portions of the results that it (the Cursor) represents. Now, I don't know if PostGre supports this, Mongo DB does, and I've tried going down that road but it's not cool. For example: do you know how much time it will pass between when a query is done and a second page of results from that query are demanded? Can the cursor stay on for that amount if time? And if it can, what does it mean exactly, will it block resources, such that if you have many lazy users, who start queries but take a long time to navigate through pages, your server might be bogged down by locked cursors?

Honestly, I think redoing a paginated query each time someone asks for a certain page is ok. First of all, you'll be returning a small number of entries (no need to display more than 10-20 entries at a time) and that's gonna be pretty fast, and second, you should more likely tune up your server so that it executes frequent request fast (add indexes, put it behind a [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) server if necessary, etc.) rather than have those queries run slow, but caching them.

Finally, if you really want to speed up full text searches, and have fancy indexes like case insensitive, prefix and suffix enabled, etc, you should take a look at [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/core/) or better yet [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) (which is Lucene on steroids) as an in-between search and indexing solution between your users and your persistence tier.

Comment: +1 good answer. I'd use Sphinx if anything. But this is a Analytics database. As such there will only be one user :D I don't clearly understand the implications of a server-side or app-side cursor when it comes to postgres. In a live db scenario I wouldn't want the cursor locking portions of the table.